# How to schedule Django shell command every week?

Tags: python, django, shell, cron

I'm trying to let a certain Python script run every week in the Django shell. How can I accomplish this? I've read about cron & django-rq, but I don't think this is possible within the given parameters.

Thanks in advance!

PS.: the code in question, it just deletes the old database and adds the updated one:

```
from formcheck.models import FormCheck
import csv

FormCheck.objects.all().delete()

formcheck_csv = open('PolisCheck.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf-8") 
reader = csv.reader(formcheck_csv)
headers = next(reader, None)[1:]

for row in reader:  
   polis_dict = {}
   for h, val in zip(headers, row[1:]):
      polis_dict[h] = val
   formcheck = FormCheck.objects.create(**polis_dict)

formcheck_csv.close()  
exit()
```

Comment: Why do you think cron won't work for you? That sounds exactly like something cron should do.

Comment: Hi deceze, I'm struggling with the fact that I need to run "python3 manage.py shell", and then add my Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the cron is for.

Instead of having separate python script create django command. Create your_app/commands/remove_db.py file.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = ''
    help = 'Remove old database'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # put your removal logic here
```

And then, in the command line:

```
$ python manage.py remove_db
```

Now, it's easy to add a new cron task to a Linux system, using crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 0 * * 0 python /var/www/myapp/manage.py remove_db
```

Comment: I see! Tbh, this is exactly what I was looking for, You're the best